# FHIR HAPI Validation for Combination of Elements

Tags: java, validation, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I have custom Structure Definition based on Observation resource. Using HAPI for the validation. Is there a way to validate the value combination?

Ex:

```
"code": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://loinc.org",
                "code": "76536-2",
                "display": "Mean Arterial Pressure, Cuff"
            }
        ]
    },
```

When this one is used, the unit of measure from the valueQuantity should have only corresponding values, not anything from the code valueset for unitofmeasure.

```
    "valueQuantity": {
      "value": 90,
      "unit": "mm Hg",
      "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
      "code": "mm[Hg]"
    }
```

In other words, for `Mean Arial Pressure` LOINC code, `valueQuantity.code` should not allow `kg`, for example.

Comment: Side note - "mm Hg" is not a valid UCUM measure.  What you actually need is "mm[Hg]".   At present, there are two mechanisms.  You can define an invariant that asserts constraints on Observation.value when Observation.code meets particular constraints, or you can leverage ObservationDefinition.  However, the HAPI validator isn't yet set up to trigger against ObservationDefinition rules, so you'd have to add custom code to make that happen.

Comment: You are right. I will update it.

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie Can you point me any documentation on ` invariant that asserts constraints on Observation.value` and `you can leverage ObservationDefinition`?

Comment: @nik Klassen provided an example of an invariant (though see my comment).  ObservationDefinition is documented here: http://hl7.org/fhir/observationdefinition.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a FHIRPath/clinical data expert but I think this should work for you

```json
{
  "resourceType": "StructureDefinition",
  "url": "https://test.com/test",
  "type": "Observation",
  "status": "draft",
  "baseDefinition": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Observation",
  "snapshot": {
    "element": [
      {
        "path": "Observation",
        "id": "Observation",
        "min": 0,
        "max": "*",
        "base": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": "*"
        },
        "constraint" : [{
          "severity" : "error",
          "expression": "code.coding.where(system = 'http://loinc.org' and code = '76536-2').exists() implies (value as Quantity).where(code='mm[Hg]' and system='http://unitsofmeasure.org').exists()"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The first part of the condition determines where you have an Observation with the appropriate code. If so it will require that your value has the right unit.

EDIT: To add some more information about what's going on here.

We are using a [FHIRPath](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/) constraint to express this more complicated validation rule.

The `.where(...)` ([docs](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/#wherecriteria-expression-collection)) condition filters down a repeated/single field if it matches the condition, in this case that's the code/system combination that matches in LOINC code you care about.

`.exists()` ([docs](https://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/#existscriteria-expression-boolean)) returns true if the collection is non-empty.

`implies` ([docs](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/#implies)) evaluates the right-hand side condition only if the left-hand side is true.

And finally the `(... as Quantity)` operator ([docs](https://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/#as-type-specifier)) is used to convert the `value[x]` field to a specific type, so more operations can be done on it.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this one?

Comment: 'unit' is a string.  You'd want to constrain Quantity.code and system.  That's where the computable values go.  So replace ".unit" with ".where(code='mm[Hg' and system='http://unitsofmeasure.org')"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lloyd, I added that to the `expression`. I also added some information about the FHIRpath operators being used here.

Comment: Should this be added to Snapshot? Can this be done in differential?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the capabilities of HAPI. Server implementers aren't required to be able to understand a differential according to the spec, the Google Healthcare API (which I work on) only supports interpreting the snapshot field. If possible I would suggest you generate the StructureDefinition with tooling so you get both snapshot and differential filled in for you.

Comment: We use Google HealthCare API as well. But when creating a profile, we need to write differential, and thats where we generally put constraints. Is there a free tool that you have in mind that can be used to generate Snapshot / differential / profile?

Comment: Also, is there a way to specify OR condition. Because, there is going to be lot of combinations to check like the one you write above in `expression`.

Comment: Lloyd probably knows more about answering those questions. For more general advice I'd recommend reaching out on chat.fhir.org